# powershell, select from simple list for already defined variable

Tags: list, powershell

Here is my scenario:
Have a PS script that patches hp machines.  all that is needed is to enter machine name and the script takes care of the rest.  I cover 2 different physical sites though, so sometimes if I need to patch machines in location A, but I'm in location B, the WAN circuit takes a decent hit transferring files.  I have an admin machine located in both places and I sync files in the evening.
Wanted to add a choice in the PS script to select if the machine is in location A or B

$sourceGB = '\machineGB\5400\630G8'

$sourceAP = '\machineAP\5400\630G8'

which would direct which machine to pull files from.
Just running into a roadblock on how to prompt for one of these options to be selected.  Probably just way overthinking it and completely missing how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: perhaps you're after `Read-Host`?

Comment: that is sounding familiar.  Any chance I could get a snippet of what that should look like?

Comment: Alternatively add a mandatory `$Location` parameter with `[ValidateSet('A', 'B')]` and PowerShell will automatically ask for the location, if you don't specify the parameter. This is even less code than `Read-Host` (which would require additional code for validation) and also self-documenting. See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/simplify-your-powershell-script-with-parameter-validation/

Comment: The linked duplicate shows you how to prompt for choices explicitly, which provides for a nicer UX than the `[Parameter(Mandatory)]` + `[ValidateSet(...)]` parameter-attributes approach @zett42 proposes; if the latter is good enough in terms of UX, however, it is much simpler to implement.